# Docker Error - cgroup mountpoint does not exist: unknown

Tags: ubuntu, docker, cgroups, docker-compose

I have a Python/Flask application (Docker) that calls a Docker in Docker (DinD) process but when that call happens, I see:

```
2023-07-07T02:21:28.733399366Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-07-07T02:21:28.733404074Z   File "/home/meta/system/simulate.py", line 117, in simulate
2023-07-07T02:21:28.733408924Z     job_container.start()
2023-07-07T02:21:28.733413666Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/models/containers.py", line 404, in start
2023-07-07T02:21:28.733419036Z     return self.client.api.start(self.id, **kwargs)
2023-07-07T02:21:28.733423792Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
2023-07-07T02:21:28.733428668Z     return f(self, resource_id, *args, **kwargs)
2023-07-07T02:21:28.733433744Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 1108, in start
2023-07-07T02:21:28.733438823Z     self._raise_for_status(res)
2023-07-07T02:21:28.733443500Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 261, in _raise_for_status
2023-07-07T02:21:28.733448503Z     raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
2023-07-07T02:21:28.733453223Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
2023-07-07T02:21:28.733458407Z     raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
2023-07-07T02:21:28.733463125Z docker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("cgroups: cgroup mountpoint does not exist: unknown")
```

I have setup cgroups through:

```
sudo mount -t cgroup -o none,name=systemd cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
echo "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=false" | sudo tee /etc/default/grub.d/cgroup.cfg
sudo update-grub
```

and if I run `lxc-checkconfig <container-id>`, I get:

```
LXC version 5.0.0~git2209-g5a7b9ce67
Kernel configuration not found at /proc/config.gz; searching...
Kernel configuration found at /boot/config-5.19.0-1025-aws
--- Namespaces ---
Namespaces: enabled
Utsname namespace: enabled
Ipc namespace: enabled
Pid namespace: enabled
User namespace: enabled
Network namespace: enabled

--- Control groups ---
Cgroups: enabled
Cgroup namespace: enabled

Cgroup v1 mount points:
/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd

Cgroup v2 mount points:
/sys/fs/cgroup

Cgroup v1 freezer controller: missing
Cgroup v1 clone_children flag: enabled
Cgroup device: enabled
Cgroup sched: enabled
Cgroup cpu account: enabled
Cgroup memory controller: enabled
Cgroup cpuset: enabled

--- Misc ---
Veth pair device: enabled, loaded
Macvlan: enabled, not loaded
Vlan: enabled, not loaded
Bridges: enabled, loaded
Advanced netfilter: enabled, loaded
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_MASQUERADE: enabled, not loaded
CONFIG_IP6_NF_TARGET_MASQUERADE: enabled, not loaded
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CHECKSUM: enabled, not loaded
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_COMMENT: enabled, not loaded
FUSE (for use with lxcfs): enabled, not loaded

--- Checkpoint/Restore ---
checkpoint restore: enabled
CONFIG_FHANDLE: enabled
CONFIG_EVENTFD: enabled
CONFIG_EPOLL: enabled
CONFIG_UNIX_DIAG: enabled
CONFIG_INET_DIAG: enabled
CONFIG_PACKET_DIAG: enabled
CONFIG_NETLINK_DIAG: enabled
```

Thoughts on what configuration I am missing to enable cgroups to mitigate the error?

The server is:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```